# How can I extract the output of a command line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, cmd

How can I extract the output of a command line program and add it in a variable in JavaScript?

As an example, I need to extract the value "11675724" in the screenshot below

```js
    var extract = function(string) {
        var o = {};

        string.replace(/(.*?)=(.*?)(?:\|\||$)/g, function(all, key, value) {
            o[key] = value;
        });

        return o;
    };
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: how are you calling the shell command? Can you show that code please?

Comment: Use shell.js, it is an order of magnitude better than the "native" exec from node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do in JavaScript what you can do from the command line.

In this case you could extract that number before passing it to your Node.js script

You must have [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) available on your system so to extract that number you can simply do:

```sh
awk '/MemTotal/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `cmd` which implies the Microsoft Windows cmd.exe shell. An `awk` command would not normally be available. Based on the text in the question, it would appear that the `cmd` tag is inappropriate.